# How does AngularJS encode the ngClick calls to a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Here's a brief example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/x1sSw8?p=preview.

This is the HTML file:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <p>Hello {{main.name}}!
     My current value for <code>main.value</code> is {{main.value}}.</p>
  <button ng-click="main.doSomething()">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Here is the `app.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'World';
  this.value = 0;
  this.doSomething = function(){
    this.value += 5;
  }

  this.doSomethingElse = function(){
    this.value -= 5;
  }
});
```

When I click the button, I normally expect the counter to go up in increments of 5. When I inspect the button and change the `ng-click` function to `doSomethingElse()`, why does it still continue to increment?

I understand I'm not directly changing the event listeners, so I wonder how AngularJS is protecting the controllers from outside tampering (like in the example I described). My guess is that it builds event listeners up after it parses the DOM for the first time (reading `ng-click` attributes and all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I inspect the button and change the ng-click function to doSomethingElse(), why does it still continue to increment?

You should check out the compilation & linking processes in Angular. The short reason is that, angular goes over these elements once they are created, not every time you click it. Since it is scanned and parsed by angular when the element is created, manually changing it by hand does not change anything, because angular does not check out what's written in there.

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Comment: I think this answers my question. Is there a particular reason why manually changing it by hand (which changes the DOM) is not recognized by AngularJS -- while doing an action such as deleting an element out of the DOM using `app.controller` is?

Comment: I think it is for performance reasons. Every time you click, angular has to parse that string, make up a function for that to be run. For single clicks, the performance won't matter but if it's for a huge list of items with a more often triggered event, it would slow it down. Besides, once they have parsed it, it doesn't make much sense to re-parse the string that is going to be the same 99.97% of the time. It's not expected to be dynamic.

Comment: To get the idea, you can take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse . I have also written a blog post about $parse back in the day, might help too: https://umur.io/advanced-angular-parse/

Comment: To be more exact, See: [ngEventDirs.js#L47](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L47), the `ng-click` directive parse the expression only once during compile time. There is no `attrs.$observe()` or something like that.